# at command force script not to read from text file

Tags: linux, at-command

I have a script with the name  `bckp2` and a text file with the name `variables.txt`. When I am running the script like that in the terminal `./bckp2` it works exactly as I want, but when I try to run it with the `at` like this `at -f bckp2 19:30` it doesn't work, it doesn't do the same thing. With the `at` command it seems like it doesn't read from the file and I have no idea why.

script `bckp2` Reads 3 words from the text file `variables.txt` and is using them as source and destination for `tar` command. Just ignore the first word it's for testing

```
let count=0

while read line; do
 for word in $line; do
  if [ $count -eq 0 ]
   then
     username=$word
  elif [ $count -eq 1 ]
   then
     source=$word
  elif [ $count -eq 2 ]
   then
     destination=$word
  fi
  let count=count+1
 done
done < variables.txt

echo $destination $source  > test.txt
tar -cvf $destination.tar $source
```

Text file `variables.txt`

```
valkon fake faketar
```

In the script `bckp2` I am saving the file content into variables, only to see if the `at` works or not, and it doesn't. It's writing to file blank text, so I assume that the script doesn't read from file at all. But as I told you, when I am running it like `./bckp2` it works.

Comment: Your whole `while read ... < variables.txt` would be better written as `read username source destination < variables.txt`... Keep in mind that jobs run via `at` or `batch` may not have entirely the same environment as your terminal session (although it does try to preserve much of it), and they are often run by `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` - so you may need a `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script...

Comment: Yes this it, everything you said solved my problem, the `while` loop and the `#!/bin/bash` . Can you answer the question so I will be able to accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` and `batch` default to interpreting commands with `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`. If you want to use a different shell, you need to format your script appropriately, by adding `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script.

Also, your unnecessarily complicated loop for reading variables could be simply replaced with

```
read username source destination < variables.txt
```